# Angular EventEmitter Error: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child

I am getting the type error, "Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1" despite following this tutorial to a T.
https://youtu.be/I317BhehZKM?t=57s

I have specified:

```
  newUserInfoComplete:boolean = false
```

yet I am getting the error specified above on `<boolean>` in this line:

```
  @Output() newUserInfoCompleteEvent = new EventEmitter <boolean> ();
```

Also, if I simply omit `<boolean>` I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

and this.NewUserInfoComplete is underlined here:

```
this.newUserInfoCompleteEvent.emit(this.newUserInfoComplete);
```

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { slideToRight } from '../../../../router.animations';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';
import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-user-input',
  templateUrl: './new-user-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-user-input.component.css'],
  animations: [slideToRight()]
})
export class NewUserInputComponent implements OnInit {

  newUserInfoComplete:boolean = false

  @Output() newUserInfoCompleteEvent = new EventEmitter <boolean> ();

  constructor(private router: Router, r: ActivatedRoute) {
    r.url.subscribe((s: UrlSegment[]) => {
      console.log("url", s); //https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-understanding-router-state-7b5b95a12eab
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }



  sendNewUserInfoComplete(){
    this.newUserInfoCompleteEvent.emit(this.newUserInfoComplete);
  }


  displaySibling() {
    console.log(this.router);
    this.router.navigate(['../', { outlets: { newuserorginfo: ['newuserorginfo'] } }])
  }

  closeBlade() {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { newuserinput: null } }]);
  }

}
```

Comment: PSA: Please stop adding answers that just say "Import from angular instead of some other path." The top answer already says this.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Try importing `EventEmitter` from `@angualar/core` instead of from `protractor`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: By default it was importing the EventEmitter from 'Events'. Just be sure to see where its being imported from.

Comment: My import was : import { EventEmitter } from 'events'. Changing it to @angular/core fixed it.

Comment: Yeah I'm using vscode and I'm not sure why it auto-imported from the wrong place. This was definitely my problem

Comment: VS Code still auto-imports from protractor, this answer solved the problem for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: VS Code auto import it from `stream`

Answer (score 9):

I forgot to check my imports!  Darn.  I was using PROTRACTOR'S event emitter and not angular core Event Emitter

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { slideToRight } from '../../../../router.animations';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-user-input',
  templateUrl: './new-user-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-user-input.component.css'],
  animations: [slideToRight()]
})
export class NewUserInputComponent implements OnInit {

  newUserInfoComplete = false;

  @Output() newUserInfoCompleteEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private router: Router, r: ActivatedRoute) {
    r.url.subscribe((s: UrlSegment[]) => {
      console.log("url", s); //https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-understanding-router-state-7b5b95a12eab
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }



  sendNewUserInfoComplete() {
    this.newUserInfoCompleteEvent.emit(this.newUserInfoComplete);
  }


  displaySibling() {
    console.log(this.router);
    this.router.navigate(['../', { outlets: { newuserorginfo: ['newuserorginfo'] } }])
  }

  closeBlade() {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { newuserinput: null } }]);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the top answer, don't import `EventEmitter` from '*protractor*', import it from '*@angular/core*'.

Why it has happened: because you used `EventEmmiter` **before** importing it, so in that case it automatically imports from '*protractor*' module.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { slideToRight } from '../../../../router.animations';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';
import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-user-input',
  templateUrl: './new-user-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-user-input.component.css'],
  animations: [slideToRight()]
})
export class NewUserInputComponent {

  newUserInfoComplete = false;
  @Output() newUserInfoCompleteEvent = new EventEmitter <boolean> ();

  constructor(private router: Router, r: ActivatedRoute) {
    r.url.subscribe((s: UrlSegment[]) => {
      console.log("url", s);
    });
  }
  sendNewUserInfoComplete(){
    this.newUserInfoCompleteEvent.emit(!!this.newUserInfoComplete);
  }


  displaySibling() {
    console.log(this.router);
    this.router.navigate(['../', { outlets: { newuserorginfo: ['newuserorginfo'] } }])
  }

  closeBlade() {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { newuserinput: null } }]);
  }

}
```

try this

Comment: when you assign a variable you dont have to set the type of data. TS automatically set it for you. and if you dont implement the Oninit delete it

Comment: Thank you so much for the 'try this' every little bit helps!!  Didn't fix it but I found the problem bc of you none the less.... knew something looked funky